# Asyncio create_subprocess_exec FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python, subprocess, python-asyncio, moviepy

I'm trying to create a async pipe that can be used to interface with a sub-process that I create. I'm having trouble with a file not found error when trying to create the process. As you can see in the code below I'm able to create the sub-process just fine using regular `Popen` in a synchronous manner. Can anyone help me get beyond this error?

Code:

```py
# I've created the command and args string/dictionary above. They are all valid. 
# I can run the command from the command line and it works
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter().pprint
pp(popen_params)

print(" ".join(cmd))

sp.Popen(cmd, **popen_params)

print("Made it past initially creating the pipe")

self.async_proc = self.loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(" ".join(cmd), **popen_params))
```

Output:

```
{'bufsize': 0, 'stderr': -1, 'stdin': -3, 'stdout': -1}
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i /Users/OWNER/Google Drive/yolo.mp4 -loglevel error -f image2pipe -vf scale=1280:720 -sws_flags bicubic -pix_fmt rgb24 -vcodec rawvideo -
Made it past initially creating the pipe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "movie_trial.py", line 97, in <module>
    clip = VideoFileClip("/Users/OWNER/Google Drive/yolo.mp4")
  File "/Users/OWNER/Documents/Projects/moivepy_vendoring/moviepy/video/io/VideoFileClip.py", line 94, in __init__
    loop=self.loop)
  File "/Users/OWNER/Documents/Projects/moivepy_vendoring/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_reader.py", line 72, in __init__
    self.async_initialize()
  File "/Users/OWNER/Documents/Projects/moivepy_vendoring/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_reader.py", line 119, in async_initialize
    self.async_proc = self.loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(" ".join(cmd), **popen_params))
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 484, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/asyncio/subprocess.py", line 225, in create_subprocess_exec
    stderr=stderr, **kwds)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1211, in subprocess_exec
    bufsize, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 200, in _make_subprocess_transport
    **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_subprocess.py", line 39, in __init__
    stderr=stderr, bufsize=bufsize, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 706, in _start
    universal_newlines=False, bufsize=bufsize, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i /Users/OWNER/Google Drive/yolo.mp4 -loglevel error -f image2pipe -vf scale=1280:720 -sws_flags bicubic -pix_fmt rgb24 -vcodec rawvideo -': '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i /Users/OWNER/Google Drive/yolo.mp4 -loglevel error -f image2pipe -vf scale=1280:720 -sws_flags bicubic -pix_fmt rgb24 -vcodec rawvideo -'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the following as a single command

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i /Users/OWNER/Google Drive/yolo.mp4 -loglevel error -f image2pipe -vf scale=1280:720 -sws_flags bicubic -pix_fmt rgb24 -vcodec rawvideo -': '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i /Users/OWNER/Google Drive/yolo.mp4 -loglevel error -f image2pipe -vf scale=1280:720 -sws_flags bicubic -pix_fmt rgb24 -vcodec rawvideo -
```

Have the command only in the first argument, then pass any extra arguments as a list in the second argument. See this link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: I missed that in the documentation, I appreciate your help.